# Sistema de upload com girar imagem automáticamente como no windows 8.1 ou facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net, imagem

Hoje ao visualizar uma imagem no windows 8.1 mesmo que a imagem esteja deitada ele automáticamente entende e mostra corretamente, no windows 7 aparece a imagem deitada.
Ao enviar essa imagem para sites como facebook ela aparece correto.
Porém ao enviar para um upload normal ela aparece deitada.

Pensei que o sistema lia o EXIF da foto porém a imagem foi feita por uma câmera que aparentemente não tinha sistema de saber se estava deitada ou em pé.

Como fazer uma classe/componente que entenda essa foto e vire ela automáticamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a classe [`EXIFExtractor` implementada e explicada aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx?fid=207371), assim:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(pathToImageFile);
var exif = new EXIFextractor(ref bmp, "n");

if (exif["Orientation"] != null)
{

    RotateFlipType flip = OrientationToFlipType(exif["Orientation"].ToString());

    if (flip != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone) // Se a orientação já está correta
    {
        bmp.RotateFlip(flip);
        exif.setTag(0x112, "1");
        bmp.Save(pathToImageFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}


private static RotateFlipType OrientationToFlipType(string orientation)
{

    switch (int.Parse(orientation))
    {
        case 1:    
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
            break;
        case 2:    
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX;
            break;
        case 3:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
            break;
        case 4:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX;
            break;
        case 5:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX;
            break;
        case 6:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
            break;
        case 7:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX;
            break;
        case 8:    
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
            break;        
        default:    
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;    
    }

}
```

[Tirei o exemplo daqui](http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2009/08/25/correct-photo-orientation-using-exif/).

Sem o EXIF acho que não tem como.

Comment: Boa resposta. :) De fato [tem como](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/~wang/Research/cviu04_wang.pdf) fazer sem o EXIF, mas não é muito trivial. Uma opção que certamente é mais simples e talvez funcione suficientemente bem (não tenho certeza, o AP precisa testar) deve ser usar OpenCV pra [estimar a pose](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html) (o exemplo é em Python, mas deve funcionar [no porte de C#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)) de algum objeto na imagem, e então decidir a orientação a partir dela.

Comment: @LuizVieira Uma vez tentei usar o OpenCV pra reconhecimento de imagens. Era tão complicado que desisti.

Comment: Hahahaha Eu te entendo totalmente. Mas não se preocupe, isso acontece com qualquer um que usa OpenCV. :)